# Cascading dropdown for sharepoint list that works with datasheet view

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm looking for a solution that implements cascading dropdown for sharepoint lists with ability to work with datasheet view.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datasheet view in SharePoint 2010 is done by Access ActiveX component. There's no way how to change it's behavior.

Comment: Thanks Jan. is there a way to programming across this ActiveX component?